# Apache2 - Limit download speed

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.10

I am trying to find a way to limit the download speed from my server. I found the module mod_bandwidth but there is no howto on apache2.2, only for 1.3.x.

How can I limit the download speed. I have ubuntu 10.10 and apache2.2 on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_cband to manage bandwidth in Apache 2. Here is a howto:
http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling

Comment: But i am getting such error

Comment: But i am getting such error:                                   root@mail:~# apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
Reading package lists...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.16-1ubuntu3) but 2.2.16-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                       Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages